# How to install an Ubuntu remix on a separate computer?

Tags: remastersys

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 to my laptop. My friend says he wants a copy of Ubuntu (just like mine) because I have already installed ubuntu-restricted extras, Chromium, Compiz, KDE, Cairo-dock, and much more cool open source software.

So I installed Remastersys and ran this command on Terminal:

```
sudo remastersys dist
```

After that, I got an .iso file which I could use as a custom Ubuntu distro. The problem is, how do I install that .iso file on my friend's hard drive? I am sure that Ubiquity is not on my .iso file, so what other options do I have?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Burn the iso (which is a disc image) to a dvd and you will have a live disc you can install your own unique version of Ubuntu from.  Alternatively you can go to system/admin and use startup disc creator to make a live USB and install from that.